# Table missing error while maaping MySQL view to hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mapping

I am trying to map a MySql view to hibernate. But when I am getting and Table missing error while starting the application.

view is

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `mydbadmin`@`%` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `Reservation_Transaction_view` AS
select 
    convert( concat(`apst`.`Tid`,
            _utf8'-',
            `apst`.`RoomIndex`,
            _utf8'-',
            `apst`.`Rid`) using utf8) AS `id`,
    `apst`.`Tid` AS `transactionId`,
    `apst`.`RoomIndex` AS `room no`,
    `apst`.`Pid` AS `paymentId`,
    `apst`.`Rid` AS `reservationId`
from
    `agent_payment_sub_transaction` `apst`
where
    (`apst`.`Rid` <> 0)
group by `apst`.`Tid` , `apst`.`RoomIndex`
```

The mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.abc.def.entity.ReservationTransactionView"
    table="Reservation_Transaction_view" catalog="abcd">
<id name="id" type="string" />
<property name="transactionId" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="transactionId" />
</property>
<property name="roomNo" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="`room no`" />
</property>
<property name="paymentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="paymentId" />
</property>
<property name="reservationId" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="reservationId" />
</property>
```

The error is as followed.

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: Reservation_Transaction_view`

I am using MySQL and Hibernate3.0 Please Help me for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on Windows or Mac OS X. Please check you have any difference in letter cases

Comment: I tried that. but no luck.

Comment: Do you say there are no difference in table names?

Comment: no there is no change.

Comment: I did solved the problem by remove hbm2ddl.auto. but this is a temporary one. If hibernate does not differentiate between table and view than why does it find the table while validation.

Comment: The question is still open. is there a way to tell the hibernate that the mapping is for view and it don't give the missing table error while validation.